# How do I get a list of function names in a PL SQL file?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a program which will print a list of all the function names in a PL/SQL file and the subsequent function calls of each function.

Eg -

```
FUNCTION Fn_ABC (field_status    IN     VARCHAR)
  BEGIN
     Dbg('In Fn_ABC ');
     IF NOT  Fn_xyz(field_status)  THEN
     Dbg('Failed in Fn_ABC');
        field_status      := 'T';
        RETURN FALSE;
     END IF;
END Fn_ABC;
```

The output on running the required code on the above file should be:

```
Fn_ABC
    Fn_xyz
```

A depth first traversal through each function seems to be the logical choice but I am confused as to how to run it to get each function name.

Comment: @Sam This is not a duplicate you posted. Your post is referrring to SQL-SERVER and question is on Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: I wasn't sure what a "PL/SQL file" was but it appears that it refers to PL/SQL source code in an OS file. Parsing a file rather than querying the dictionary makes the task orders of magnitude harder, as normally PL/SQL is for database processing and doesn't have anything to do with files.

Answer (score 1):

No need to traverse the .sql file. Once you have created the function in database, just run this query to get all functions which your function depends on.

```
SELECT NAME, REFERENCED_NAME
  FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES
 WHERE NAME = 'FN_ABC' AND TYPE = 'FUNCTION' AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

Comment: This will show the objects which reference `FN_ABC` **provided it's a standalone function**. USER_DEPENDENCIES shows Packages and Tables but doesn't slow packaged Procedures or variables. To see those lower level objects we need to use PL\Scope, which is discussed in the duplicate thread.

Comment: @APC : Thats cool. Thanks. I wish if I worked with ( or under!) someone like you :)

Comment: @APC, PL/Scope surely?

Comment: @KaushikNayak - thanks, I appreciate the sentiment. William might not agree :)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - good spot. And it's more effort to type `\` on a mobile keyboard. What was I thinking?